# Is mysql/mongodb cluster suitable for installation on kubernetes?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I used to test installed mongodb-shard on kubernetes by helm,but I found that those helm charts are not really a qualified mongodb shard.These helm charts can correctly create Pods with names like `mongos-1` `mongod-server-1` `mongod-shard-1`,this seems to be a correct shard cluster configuration, but the appropriate mongos, mongod server instance is not created on the corresponding Pod.They just create a normal mongod instance on the corresponding pod, and there is no connection between them.Do I need to add scripts to execute commands similar to `rs.addShard(config)`?Encountered the same problem when installing mysql cluster using helm.

What I want to know is, is it not appropriate to install mysql/mongodb cluster on kubernetes in general scenarios?Is the database installed independently or deployed on Kubernetes?

Comment: Please tell us where is your cluster located?

Comment: I create multiple virtual machines running on my local computer to simulate a cluster environment，all my applications are deployed in a local cluster environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can deploy MongoDB instances on Kubernetes clusters.

Use [standalone instance](https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/tutorial/deploy-standalone/) if you want to test and develop and [replica set](https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/) for production like deployments.

Also to make things easier you can use [MongoDB Enterprise Kubernetes Operator](https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-enterprise-kubernetes#mongodb-enterprise-kubernetes-operator):

> The Operator enables easy deploys of MongoDB into Kubernetes clusters,
>   using our management, monitoring and backup platforms, Ops Manager and
>   Cloud Manager. By installing this integration, you will be able to
>   deploy MongoDB instances with a single simple command.

This guide has references to the official MongoDB documentation with more necessary details regarding:

- Install Kubernetes Operator
- Deploy Standalone
- Deploy Replica Set
- Deploy Sharded Cluster
- Edit Deployment
- Kubernetes Resource Specification
- Troubleshooting Kubernetes Operator
- Known Issues for Kubernetes Operator

So basically all you need to know in this topic.

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: I have been confused about how stateful applications are deployed on kubernetes until your answer let me know the existence of `Kubernetes Operator`.In Helm Hub, the chart of many databases is actually a single node, because distributed databases will be more troublesome.`Operator` looks like a good solution.Thank you very much!

Comment: I guess its licensed and need to pay.From documentation --  "To deploy MongoDB resources with the Kubernetes Operator, you need an Ops Manager instance." ..."Ops Manager is available as part of the MongoDB Enterprise Advanced subscription ... MongoDB Enterprise Advanced subscription is not free"